# Matlab: dynamic name for structure

Tags: matlab, variables, struct, definition

I want to create a structure with a variable name in a matlab script. The idea is to extract a part of an input string filled by the user and to create a structure with this name. For example:

```
CompleteCaseName = input('s');
USER WRITES '2013-06-12_test001_blabla';  
CompleteCaseName = '2013-06-12_test001_blabla'
casename(12:18) = struct('x','y','z');
```

In this example, *casename(12:18)* gives me the result *test001*.

I would like to do this to allow me to compare easily two cases by importing the results of each case successively. So I could write, for instance :

```
plot(test001.x,test001.y,test002.x,test002.y);
```

The problem is that the line *casename(12:18) = struct('x','y','z');* is invalid for Matlab because it makes me change a string to a struct. All the examples I find with struct are based on a definition like

```
S = struct('x','y','z');
```

And I can't find a way to make a dynamical name for *S* based on a string.

I hope someone understood what I write :) I checked on the FAQ and with Google but I wasn't able to find the same problem.

Comment: What if you have 100 tests? Will you hardcode `plot(test001.x, ..., test100.y)`? Instead, Use a cell array or a structure e.g. `s.test001.data` or better a matrix if lenghts coincide.

Comment: Remember that you can even upvote the answer you accepted `;-)`, or other that you find useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a structure with a dynamic field name.

For example,

```
mydata.(casename(12:18)) = struct;
```

will give you a struct `mydata` with a field `test001`.

You can then later add your `x`, `y`, `z` fields to this.

You can use the fields later either by `mydata.test001.x`, or by `mydata.(casename(12:18)).x`.

If at all possible, try to stay away from using `eval`, as another answer suggests. It makes things very difficult to debug, and the example given there, which directly `eval`s user input:

```
eval('%s = struct(''x'',''y'',''z'');',casename(12:18));
```

is even a *security* risk - what happens if the user types in a string where the selected characters are `system(''rm -r /''); a`? Something bad, that's what.

Comment: I will go with this solution. I did not think to test a field based on a dynamic name and to add fields after. Thank you, I almost gave up on my idea.

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented, the **best case scenario** is when all your `x` and `y` vectors have **same length**. In this case you can store all data from the different files into 2 matrices and call `plot(x,y)` to plot each column as a series.

Alternatively, you can use a **cell array** such that:

```
c = cell(2,nufiles);
for ii = 1:numfiles
     c{1,ii} = import x data from file ii
     c{2,ii} = import y data from file ii
end
plot(c{:})
```

**A structure**, on the other hand

```
s.('test001').x = ...
s.('test001').y = ...
```

Comment: As I write for the other answer, the idea of a dynamic field name will certainly work. Thank you, for you answer. And I will never use eval() !

Answer (score -2):

Use eval:

```
eval(sprintf('%s = struct(''x'',''y'',''z'');',casename(12:18)));
```

Edit: apologies, forgot the sprintf.

Comment: I will always downvote `eval()` solutions that pop variables into workspace.

Comment: Because it's unsafe? True, but it is a valid answer to the question as-is. There are better ways to do it than what is asked, of course.

Comment: No, simply because unexperienced users tend to abuse `eval()`. They get used to wrong data management practices (programming approaches) which ultimately bring them back to the forum asking incomprehensible and non constructive questions. Therefore, my downvotes on `eval()` tend to warn against such approaches before the user has deeply built his script on it. As per my comment to the OP, after evaling such a structure, the next step would be to eval the `plot()` command and so forth.

Comment: Fair enough, I agree with all that.