# Import matrix definition from Excel into MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I have an Excel sheet that contains the definitions of a structure including its content that I would like to import into MATLAB. For example, the definition in two Excel cells may look like this and is saved as a concatenated string:

```
testCase.expectedSolution.long = [1,2,3 ; 4,5,6 ; 7,8,9];
testCase.expectedSolution.short = [10,11,12 ; 13,14,15 ; 16,17,18];
```

I am using these definitions as expected solutions for unit tests in MATLAB. Right now, I am simply doing copy & paste from Excel into the MATLAB code in order to define the structure in MATLAB. However, I am wondering whether it is possible (and suitable) to import these strings into MATLAB. In reality, I have up to thousands of strings that will be generated from a VBA macro in Excel.

Comment: Can you upload an image of the Excel sheet in order to get a better idea of how it looks?

Comment: @Cebri The range that I copy & paste looks exactly like I mentioned in the first place. There are a lot of structure definitions (in fact thousands) in one particular column.
As a matter of fact, all the structure field names as well as its content will be created in Excel based on settings that I can perform in different cells.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now. So one cell contains `testCase.expectedSolution.long = [1,2,3 ; 4,5,6 ; 7,8,9];`, the cell underneath contains `testCase.expectedSolution.short = [10,11,12 ; 13,14,15 ; 16,17,18];` and so on. And you want to create a [`struct`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) whose fields and values are defined in each one of the cells of your Excel sheet. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly, the point is that the structure's field names as well as its content will be created in Excel. Right now, I created them using string concatenation and save the complete MATLAB compatible definition of one particular field in one particular Excel cell. I am now wondering whether my copy & paste way is the most efficient way to get these definitions back into MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the Excel workbook shown in the image, named it `Book1.xlsx` and saved it in my working directory.

[image: Excel workbook]

Then I created the following MATLAB script which uses [`xlsread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to read the entire A column of the first sheet (Sheet1) and then uses [`eval`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to execute the string contained in every cell, as if you would have typed every instruction manually in the Command Window:

```
filename = 'Book1.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A:A';

[~, txt, ~] = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);

for i = 1:size(txt, 1)
    eval(txt{i});
end
```

This is the output:

```
>> testCase.expectedSolution
ans = 
     long: [3x3 double]
    short: [3x3 double]
```

---

Be careful with `eval` because:

> Many common uses of the `eval` function are less efficient and are more
>   difficult to read and debug than other MATLAB functions and language
>   constructs. For more information, see [Alternatives to the eval
>   Function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

I strongly suggest you to read [TUTORIAL: Why Variables Should Not Be Named Dynamically (eval)](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) so you understand the implications of using `eval`.

Quoting [Sam Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17062899/3599179):

> `eval` is even a security risk - what happens if the user types in a
>   string where the selected characters are `system(''rm -r /''); a`?
>   Something bad, that's what.

Comment: Wow, your solution is working and it saves me some time because I don't have to copy & paste from Excel. I'll take a look at that document, but I think I can handle the risk. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`readtable`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) or [`importdata`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html).

`xlsread` or `uiimport` might work too, see this link for [available options](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-spreadsheets.html).

Comment: The problem with all these function is that I need to specify a varaible name that I assign the values from Excel to. In my case, the name of the structure and its corresponding fields will be defined in Excel and I need to bring these names back into MATLAB.
Right now, I am copying, let's say, the range B2:B2000 and pasting the content into the MATLAB code. The Excel cells contains structure definitions MATLAB code is directly understanding.

Comment: @Andi : Mkay... So I see 2 options, either you load the Excel range in a MATLAB array and amend your code, or you could generate your MATLAB code directly from VBA to a txt file or another format if it fits better. I'm not sure which one would be the best as I don't know your code! ;)